# VBA function that sets a range depending on adjacent cells

Tags: excel, range, vba

This question is a little tricky for me to explain but I hope it will somehow make sense to someone. 
At the moment in terms of setting ranges on my cells, I have always given it some form of a limit (e.g Range("A1:A10")) before adding my functions, but I now want to make a macro that is more flexible whereby the limit is based on the last cell row that is recorded on a column in  the spreadsheet. The spreadsheet I use in question is linked to a database in which i refresh on a weekly basis and the range of rows I get can vary from one day being 250 rows, the next being 300 and sometimes back to 275 for example.
There must be an easier way around this where I dont have to change the Range limit on vba macro every time I refresh the spreadsheet. I can imagine it being such a simple solution though I cant figure out how to go about this without me reading too much into it and further confusing myself. Am I looking at using a form of a loop here in this case and if so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

To get the last row you can do something like this

```
Dim last_row as Integer, input_sheet as Worksheet, col_number as Integer
col_number = 1
Set input_sheet.Sheets(1) ' change it accordingly
last_row = input_sheet.Cells(input_sheet.Rows.Count, col_number).End(xlUp).Row
```

What this does basically is select the last row of column A of the worksheet and replicates the action of "Ctrl" + "Up direction". So you end up at the last row. You could modify this accordingly according to your needs.